# git commit -v [file] showing full diff rather than manual patch created via git add -e [file]

Tags: git

I have manually added changes to the index with

```
git add -e [file]
```

.. and manually editing the patch, which has applied cleanly.

```
Git diff --cached [file]
```

... correctly shows the changes I want to apply.

However when I do

```
git commit -v [file]
```

The diff shown at the bottom of the commit message shows all the changes to the file since my last commit, not just my manually edited patch.

Is this a bug? or correct behaviour? It seems that this diff should be generated by diffing the index to the latest commit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't list the filename on the `git commit` command. Saying `git commit foo` will commit all changes in `foo` regardless of what's already been staged.

Comment: You're right, thanks.  Don't know why I specified the file to commit, that's what the index is for!